# how to change the color of a spinner prompt

Tags: android-layout, android-spinner

I have a spinner with a custom background and I need to change the initially displayed text (the initial prompt) from black to white.

This is what I've got at the moment

[image]

There are plenty of answers on SO and elsewhere on how to change the spinner ITEMS color using an adapter but nothing (that I can find) on how to change the initial text (the 'Android' in my example).

How do I change the color of the initial spinner prompt?

Answer (score 0):

Blush ...  Oops, I've just found out for myself.  The answer is to replicate `simple_spinner_item.xml` and put it into the layout directory.  I had done that but called it `simple_spinner.xml`, not `simple_spinner_item.xml`.